# Looking for simple code to play streaming audio by HTTP from m3u

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I looking for sample code for iOS (I guess, using AVMediaPlayer or AVPlayer) to play streaming audio, from URL (our current server URL is http://server.local:8008/ourradio.aac.m3u).

Audio stream also should be played, when application in background mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

M3U is a playlist format. It is a plain text file containing the locations of music files, most notably MP3 files. Read the [Wikipedia Article about M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U). Then play each MP3 using this if you really want it on an iPhone:

```
AVPlayer *musicPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:musicLinkFromM3uFile];
[musicPlayer play];
```

where `musicLinkFromM3uFile` is the location of the MP3 file read from the m3u file.

**EDIT:** And to be able to continue playing in background you will need to setup an audio session with category `kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback`. To do that add the following lines of codes to your applicationDidLoad in the app delegate:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

You will also need to set `UIBackgroundModes` in your Info.plist to `audio`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. AVAudioPlayer does not support streaming via HTTP. Try using AVPlayer instead.

Comment: maybe, you have got a some sample?

Comment: I've edited my answer, have a look at it. But to make it really well working you will have to read into AVPlayer class reference since error handling is a bit harder then with AVAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.mysite.com/test.mp3";
urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];   
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlStream];   
[player play];
```

Comment: m3u and .mp3 are different @alexandresoli